# Netbeans 10.0 <main classes not found> for simple Hello world program

Tags: java, ubuntu, netbeans

Hi, I just installed Netbeans 10.0 and I can't run my Java project because apparently my main is missing but the class main is there!
I tried to right click the project and create a new main class but it didn't help.

**the error**

[image: Click here for the see the error]

Comment: looks like some issue with the JDK setup, even String is highlighted in red. What error does it give you if you click on the red exclamation mark?

Comment: and for the  underlined String in red, in the main method,  can you tell us what is it showing as error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change the package name to another one which different from the project name, for example make it "hello_pkg", same for the class name, try to make all the 3 have different names to avoid any confusion.

for example:

- Project name: helloProject
- Package: hello_pkg
- Class : Hello

**EDIT:(after providing more information in comments)**

Netbeans 10 doesn't support JDK 14, use JDK 10 instead (or older)

Comment: after renaming the name of the package, make sure that you changed the package import in the class too. also can you please provide us what is the error in the underlined package and String (underlined in red)

Comment: The error in package line is: "cannot access java.lang, Fatal error unable to find pakcage, java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath" / The error on the main line is: "cannot find symbol, symbol class String, location: class Hello". I changed the package line in package hello_pkg;

Comment: what is the java version and netbeans version?

Comment: The netbeans version is the 10.0, the java version is this: openjdk version "14.0.1" 2020-04-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 14.0.1+7-Ubuntu-1ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.1+7-Ubuntu-1ubuntu1, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: try to use an older version of JDK (11 for example or older), Netbeans 10 might not support JDK 14

Comment: I just get jdk 11: openjdk version "11.0.7" 2020-04-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.7+10-post-Ubuntu-3ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.7+10-post-Ubuntu-3ubuntu1, mixed mode, sharing)
but it still doesn't work. I still have the 2 error in the lines and netbeans stil doesn't find the main...

Comment: make sure that jdk 11 is the associated jdk with Netbeans

Comment: how? On the Java platform section of netbeans is selected JDK 11 by default

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/593627/how-to-set-new-jdk-home-in-netbeans-ide-after-java-update-netbeans-ide-refuses

Comment: after changing jdk, right click on the project, go to properties, then libraries, update "Java Platform"

Comment: There is no update button in the libraries but the jdk for the project is the same jdk for netbeans, jdk 11

Comment: Netbeans 10 is supposed to support jdk 11, but after making some searches, there are some people ,who are using Ubing, are facing the same problem as yours, and after using JDK 10 it was fixed . this time, it should work for sure

Comment: I just "fixed" the problem by using the JDK 10 in the project an by disabling the compile on save options. I'm not sure if is this how is supposed to work for programming in Java using netbeans on Ubuntu but since it work, i will go for it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: you can enable the compile on save options.it is not related to your problem. do you have the problem even if it is enabled?

Comment: actually, Netbeans 10 supports JDK 10 (same version of both) , it can supports JDK 11 too if you follow specific steps to configure it (take a look here https://websiteforstudents.com/apache-netbeans-ide-10-0-released-heres-how-to-install-with-openjdk-on-ubuntu-16-04-18-04-18-10/ ), but it will work with JDK 10 by default

Answer (score 0):

Just find out how to fix the problem but i'm not sure if it's a real solution.
-Download JDK 10
-Open Netbeans >Tools>Java platform>add platform and select the JDK 10 folder
-Then disable the compile on save options in your project by doing right click on the project>proprieties>compiling and turn off the compile on save options

Always remember to set JDK 10 on your project by right click on your project>Proprieties>Libraries>And select JDK 10!